# load dynamic content from database to App.config in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want the below attributes to load contents in Config/App.php from the database. I tried config('App')->attribute but it's not working.

```
public $defaultLocale = 'en'
public $negotiateLocale = false;
public $supportedLocales = ['en','ar'];
```

Answer (score 0):

set
public  $negotiateLocale = false;
to
public $negotiateLocale = true;

send  header

Accept-Language  En

to change content by lang

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.